# Can diapers cause Toxic-Shock-Syndrome (TSS) like tampons do?

Tags: infant, sanitation, tampons

Can diapers cause Toxic-Shock-Syndrome (TSS) like tampons do?

I know that tampons have notoriously been linked to TSS if they are not changed frequently enough.....

While I know that diapers are not inserted internally in the infant, I was wondering if I diaper has been neglected to be changed for many hours if the bacteria could work it's way into the system? I know it's never mentioned so it must be extremely rare if it did, but is it possible?

Or is the staph or strep bacteria caused by blood, and hence just linked to tampons in this case?